# CentOS5, RHEL5, Java dependent Packages, Alternate JVM/JDK

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm, java

Specifically regarding Java dependent packages, such as ant. Is it possible to install them via rpm, when using an alternate JVM/JDK?  For example, If I install the Oracle JDK, can I use an ant package without installing OpenJDK? Is there anyway this can be done from an RPM?

I know I can specify which JDK to use, by executing `update-alternatives --config java`.  Additionally I'm specifying a JAVA_HOME,  which works as expected. The only available choices seem to be, keeping 3 different JDK's installed, or installing everything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. `rpm -i --nodeps` will install the rpms  without the dependency-check.

The more interesting question seems to be how to do this with `yum`.

If you can get the source-rpm of an alternative java, you might put an "Obsoletes jdk" into the spec-file...